# Does a "binary sort" algorithm exist?

Tags: algorithm

Is there a sorting algorithm that is named "binary sort"? Like merge sort, selection sort, or the other kinds of sorting, does a binary sort exist?

Comment: Perhaps you mean [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)? In any case, your question does not provide enough information for meaningful answers. Please take your time and rewrite the question to include useful information/details.

Comment: @Paul @pst I don't see your problems in understanding the answer: Is there a popular sorting algorithm who's name is "binary sort"?

Comment: @Dave: I was responding to the original question, which was even shorter and more vague than the current version - look back through the edits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's [this](http://www.geneffects.com/briarskin/theory/binary/index.html) and there's binary insertion sort. The two are pretty similar. They're both quadratic (`O(n^2)`) time algorithms.

Both algorithms do `O(n log n)` number of comparisons, but in practice you would also have to move elements around, which would make the entire algorithm quadratic.

Comment: I want to write an algorithm(this is not a home work) and I want to sort at first and then using binary serach for finding two elements that their sum equal to 9 and the running time of this algorithm should be theta(nlogn) can I use merge sort for sorting and Binary search for searching?

Comment: @matin1234:nope.but you can remove the numbers more than 8.and sort the left numbers, loop from up and down(it is a little strange) for numbers resulting a sum of nine.it is O(n).

Comment: @matin1234 - yes you can. For each element `i` binary search in `[i + 1, n]` for an element equal to `9 - a[i]`. This is after sorting of course. @Behrooz - `100 + (-91) = 9`.

Comment: If I understood right, the only difference between binary insertion sort and the sorting algorithm in the provided link is that it chooses the next element randomly. It seems to me there's no benefit of doing so and therefore it is slower than binary insertion sort.

Answer (score 6):

The `JDK` uses a "binary sort" for arrays < size 32 within its `Arrays.sort()` method. This is actually an `insertion sort` but using `binary search` to find the next item instead of linear search.

Here is the code from `JDK7`

```
private static void binarySort(Object[] a, int lo, int hi, int start) {
    assert lo <= start && start <= hi;
    if (start == lo)
        start++;
    for ( ; start < hi; start++) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Comparable<Object> pivot = (Comparable) a[start];

        // Set left (and right) to the index where a[start] (pivot) belongs
        int left = lo;
        int right = start;
        assert left <= right;
        /*
         * Invariants:
         *   pivot >= all in [lo, left).
         *   pivot <  all in [right, start).
         */
        while (left < right) {
            int mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
            if (pivot.compareTo(a[mid]) < 0)
                right = mid;
            else
                left = mid + 1;
        }
        assert left == right;

        /*
         * The invariants still hold: pivot >= all in [lo, left) and
         * pivot < all in [left, start), so pivot belongs at left.  Note
         * that if there are elements equal to pivot, left points to the
         * first slot after them -- that's why this sort is stable.
         * Slide elements over to make room for pivot.
         */
        int n = start - left;  // The number of elements to move
        // Switch is just an optimization for arraycopy in default case
        switch (n) {
            case 2:  a[left + 2] = a[left + 1];
            case 1:  a[left + 1] = a[left];
                     break;
            default: System.arraycopy(a, left, a, left + 1, n);
        }
        a[left] = pivot;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a part of TimSort Algo. But it looks fuzzy. can someone explain this? How it differ with the merge sort?

Comment: @RasikaPerera This is a insertion sort which uses binary search to find the position where each unsorted item must be inserted in the sorted list under construction. It performs less comparisons than the traditional insertion sort which searches for that position linearly. The number of item moves is the same, but you can move all items which are greater than the unsorted item at once (using System.arraycopy() in the Java implementation above), which *could* be faster than moving each item separately on some system architectures.

Comment: @javadba it'd be nice to make it clear in your answer that this is a binary *insertion sort*. It just uses binary search instead of linear search to find the position of each unsorted item in the already sorted list.

Answer (score 4):

A binary sort is a very fast algorithm which involves bit testing.  It has a single pass for each bit in the sortable item.  For each pass, if the bit is set then the sortable item is stacked at one end of the buffer.  If the bit is not set then the item is stacked at the other end of the buffer.  Starting the sort at the least significant bit and dealing with the next bits in ascending order will result in the sorted list.  I wrote one of these on an early 8086 in 1983 forthe Scottish Education Department.
Steve Pitts

Comment: This sounds like radix sort.  Would you have any further clarification on how the algo you describe differs from radix?

Comment: @javadba: there's more than one way to roll this: The way I read the description above, you copy each item in each pass "to the other buffer", differences from radix-2-sort: no histogram passes, not stable. One alternative looks a hybrid with *quicksort*: from the left, find item with bit set; from the right, find item with bit clear, exchange - in place, not stable.

Answer (score 0):

There are some sort's that involve splitting into two peices (merge sort) but I don't beleive that there is a sort called exactly "binary sort".

Answer (score 0):

We do not have a binary sort algorithm, but we do have binary search on a sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your looking for but if your looking for a suitable binary sort algorithm then you want to be aware of your requirements. Each algorithm has its own strengths and weakness.

For example, are you looking for an algorithm that give fastest average performance (e.g. heap search) or fasted worst case (slowest operation) performance (e.g. balanced binary tree). Some are slow if you also need to iterate from one item to the next. If your doing many random operations you are probably more interested in average performance but if you have a need to ensure that any operation is faster than X milliseconds then you may want a different algorithm. Some can be slow if you always adding items at the end of the collection etc.

So have a google for keywords like:

- Red black tree
- heap search
- balanced trees, e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/redblackcs.aspx?msg=931557

It all comes down to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a binary sort but the actual array sorted should be in Opposite sense.(i.e., Say you want to sort an array of integers in ascending order...for that, you must have the actual array in descending order.)